# Any way to hold a connection to mysql database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

Im trying to optimize some of my PHP code. I found out that most time of my PHP script is spent during the connection to my mysql database at the beginning of the script.

I only connect to the database once at the beginning and close the database connection at the end of the script.

But for each user requesting this page a new connection has to be established.

Is there a way to hold a reference to the database and share it for all requests?

Comment: "I figured that most time..." you figured how? Did you actually test it? Doing this sort of thing is useless without testing where the bottleneck is.

Comment: You may also want to look into caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your connection persistent (for PDO use [PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)), but my recomandation is to find out why your script is spending a lot of time connecting to mysql and make some improvments there.

Consider this:

- Use MySQL server IP instead of hostname, to eliminate time needed to resolve dns.
- Disable mysql autocompletition: (comment `skip-auto-rehash` from `my.cnf`)
- If you make a lot of queries which will return the same thing over and over again, consider using a caching system to cache for query results.
- Post your code on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to benefit from others expertise on further improving your code.
- To further debug the problem, connect from console to MySQL server and check the time needed to open connection, change database, select, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can achieve that.

If you're using the MySQLi extension (the old one without the *i* at the end is **outdated!**), you can create a persistent connection by passing `p:` as a prefix to the hostname when creating the instance:

See [mysqli::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

<sub>If you're really using the old MySQL extension, there's [mysql_pconnect](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) for persistent connections</sub>.

Alternatively, if you're using PDO, then you can use `setAttribute()` to use `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`.

Documentation on using persistent connection in [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Comment: Looks like someone took the time to revenge vote the both of you?

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Is PDO nowadays the right way to go? I will test it.

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons) for example. The main aspect is that you can use different RDBMS with PDO.

Comment: @ComFreek That's the part of PDO which is actually overrated imho. It's named parameters and a nicer API. If you switch RDBMS you have to change you queries either way.

Comment: @SebastianOberste-Vorth Yes, all `mysql_*` have been deprecated. Take a [reading of this](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) to know the reasons in details.

Comment: @PeeHaa Of course, there are several advantages which just cannot be expressed in one single comment ;) I would start with PDO when creating a new project.